# OctoberCMS DynamicPDF open or download via AJAX

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins, octobercms-backend, dynamicpdf

I am using [DynamicPDF](https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-dynamicpdf) and I am opening my file in new tab to generate my file which is working absolutely fine. Here is what I have sone so far (in one of my plugin's `update.htm` file).

```
<a href="<?= url('/'); ?>/regency-brochure" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Preview Brochure</a>
```

Now I am trying to somehow do the same by opening/downloading the same file via AJAX response. Hence I have put below code inside my `update.htm` file.

```
<button
                        type="submit"
                        
                        data-request="onPreview"
                        data-load-indicator="Loading Preview"
                        class="btn btn-primary">Preview Brochure Ajax
                    </button>
```

And Inside my controller I have done this.

```
public function onPreview()
    {        
     return PDF::loadTemplate('renatio::invoice')->download('download.pdf');
    }
```

Now as soon as I click on it, my browser getting hanged, but I am able to see some random binary long string in my response.

I have checked and read library's documentation and they are giving a tip saying...

> Tip: Download PDF via Ajax response
>
> OctoberCMS ajax framework cannot handle this type of response.
>
> Recommended approach is to save PDF file locally and return redirect to PDF file.

And I tried to open / download by using `return` but its not working.

Can someone guide me how can I solve this ? How can I make my PDF file open / download using AJAX here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I have implemented above feature.

Here is what I have done.

**update.htm**

```
 <button type="submit" data-request="onPreviewDownload" data-load-indicator="Generating Brochure..."
                            data-request-success="formSuccess( context, data, textStatus, jqXHR)" class="btn btn-primary">Preview Brochure
                        </button>

<script>
    function formSuccess( context, data, textStatus, jqXHR){        
        window.open(data.result, '_blank');        
    }    
</script>
```

**ControllerFile.php**

```
public function onPreviewDownload()
    {


        $templateCode = 'renatio::invoice'; // unique code of the template
        $storagePath =  storage_path('app/uploads/');
        $pdf_file_name =  'regency-brochure-test.pdf' ;
        $pdf_file_name_directory =  $storagePath . $pdf_file_name;
        PDF::loadTemplate($templateCode)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->save($pdf_file_name_directory);
        return $baseUrl = url(Config::get('cms.storage.uploads.path')) . '/' . $pdf_file_name;

    }
```

As you can see in **update.htm** file, I have used `data-request="onPreviewDownload"` , `data-load-indicator="Generating Brochure..."` and `data-request-success="formSuccess( context, data, textStatus, jqXHR)"`.

Then `onPreviewDownload` method in my `ControllerFile`, I have used `save` method instead of `download` method, `PDF::loadTemplate($templateCode)->setPaper('a4', 'landscape')->save($pdf_file_name_directory);` mentioned in [Documentation of DynamicPDF](https://octobercms.com/plugin/renatio-dynamicpdf) through which, I am saving the file in particular location and once I am able to save the file.

Then I am opening from my `formSuccess` method in **update.htm** file using `window.open(data.result, '_blank');`.

Hope this helps.